# Sorting release versions of the format YYYY.MM.DD in a Django queryset

Tags: python, django

I have a Django model that looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from distutils.version import LooseVersion

# Create your models here.
class ReleaseNotes(models.Model):
   
    version = models.CharField(max_length=64, db_index=True, help_text="Version/Release")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True, help_text="Status")
    release_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Release Date")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text="Description")

    def description_to_bullet_points(self):
        return self.description.split('\n')

    def release_notes_list(self):
        qs = ReleaseNotes.objects.order_by('-version')
        return sorted(qs, key=lambda qs:LooseVersion(qs.version))

    def __str__(self):
        return self.version
```

And I display the "release notes" with this template:

```
{% if release_notes_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for release_note in release_notes_list %}
        <p><b>{{ release_note.version }}</b><br>
        {% for bullet_pt in release_note.description_to_bullet_points %}
            <br>{{ bullet_pt }}
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No release notes are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

And I have this view:

```
from .models import ReleaseNotes
from django.views import generic

# Create your views here.


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    queryset = ReleaseNotes.objects.order_by('-version')
    template_name = 'release_notes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'release_notes_list'
```

I want to display the "release notes" with the newest release note on top.
But I have versions of the format `YYYY.MM.DD` so the version `2020.11.1` does not show up on top.  The version come out in this order:

```
2020.8.1
2020.7.1
2020.6.2
2020.6.1
2020.5.4
2020.5.3
2020.5.2
2020.5.1
2020.4.4
2020.4.3
2020.4.2
2020.4.1
2020.2.6
2020.2.5
2020.2.4
2020.2.3
2020.2.2
2020.2.1
2020.11.1
2020.1.4
2020.1.3
2020.1.2
2020.1.1
```

Comment: Add the view code

Comment: @JavierBuzzi I have added the view.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi I am using https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#making-friendly-template-contexts

Comment: Oh wow, this really shows how little i use Django Views, this has been here a long time. Gotcha, one last question: what db are you using?

Comment: As a side note: the model should be called "ReleaseNote", models are never plural. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies all.  I think I have it figured out.

I removed the `release_notes_list()` method from my model and changed my view to look like this:

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    queryset = ReleaseNotes
    template_name = 'release_notes/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'release_notes_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = ReleaseNotes.objects.all()
        return sorted(qs, key=lambda qs:LooseVersion(qs.version), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have access to a Oracle DB at the moment, but it *should** look like this:

```
@classmethod
def release_notes_list(cls):
    fields = [
        models.expressions.RawSQL("substr(version, 1, instr(version,'.') - 1)", []),
        models.expressions.RawSQL("length(substr(version, instr(version,'.') + 1))", []),
        models.expressions.RawSQL("substr(version, instr(version,'.') + 1)", []),
    ]
    return cls.objects.extra(order_by=fields)
```

**Original**:

The reason I asked for the database type is because the efficient solution is PER-DATABASE type. I am going to assume you're using postgres.

```
@classmethod
def release_notes_list(cls):
    field = models.expressions.RawSQL("string_to_array(version, '.')::int[]", [])
    return cls.objects.extra(order_by=[field])
```

*If you're NOT using postgres, let me know and I will update by answer*

This is double the speed of [your](https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/5ee41199cc1a76976a33cd7260709468#file-django_view_sort-py-L200) solution and [sanane sanane](https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/5ee41199cc1a76976a33cd7260709468#file-django_view_sort-py-L211) is crashing due to a TypeError.

Here it is in action: https://gist.github.com/kingbuzzman/5ee41199cc1a76976a33cd7260709468#file-django_view_sort-py-L110 /w tests

Comment: I am using Oracle.

Comment: @RedCricket test that.. i can't speak for the performance though

Comment: There is a performance problem with my solution. But I suspect it is related to my description_to_bullet_points method. Which cannot be avoided because easy of use trumps easy of use over performance.

Comment: @RedCricket what you're saying makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You can change the place in the model with the following and try

```
def release_notes_list(self):
    qs = ReleaseNotes.objects.order_by('-version')
    return sorted(qs, key=lambda qs:LooseVersion(datetime.strptime(qs, '%Y/%M/%D')) )
```

Comment: This throws a `TypeError`